How can I able to exclude 'Category' and 'Tag' slug from the URL in Wordpress without reloading to new site?
in functions.php, I wrote this code:
function remove_category($link) {
    if (!is_admin() && (is_category() || is_tag())) {

        
        $category = get_queried_object();
        $category_id = $category->term_id;
        $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);

        $url = $category_link;
        $arr = parse_url($url);
        $path = $arr['path'];
        $str_to_arr = explode('/', $path);
        $archive = $str_to_arr[2];
        $new_url = str_replace('/' . $archive, '', $url);
        
        return $new_url;
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('term_link', 'remove_category',10,1);

The code actually filters out category or tags based on the custom theme I am working on.
Now I have tried applying 'term_link' filter hook, but the site breaks. How can I able to achieve this?

how does it break? Filters like term_link or post_link are for changing the URL as its printed out in HTML, it doesn't change the URL of the term/post or influence rewrite rules in anyway, only the URL as it appears in the final HTML output. You could make it return anything you want but WordPress won't know that you want the term archive when that URL is visited. return 'https://google.com'; is just as valid

No it doesnt, sorry for late response, but now I have figured out that I have to do it with 'term_link'
